# Is there general way to prove that for a given function exists formula with a constant amount of operations?

Tags: combinatorics, functions, computational-complexity, semigroups, idempotents

E.g there is a formula for a function that gives a number of idempotent functions for a set with finite size. The solution is $\sum_{k=1}^n{n\choose k}k^{n-k}$
but you need to sum intermediate results.

So the number of operations is dependent on the size of the set. But is there any solution for this function that does require only a constant amount of operations? How can I prove it? Is there a general way to conclude that function can have a formula with a constant amount of operations given the fact that we already have a formula with the number of operations dependent on the input or have proven that such must exist?

Comment: Since there is no formula given at the OEIS entry for this sequence, https://oeis.org/A000248, it is overwhelmingly likely that none exists.

Comment: What do you mean by "a number of idempotent functions for a finite set",

Comment: @J.-E. Pin
How many functions $f(f) = f$ if $f$ is $E\rightarrow E$ ? 
If the set $E$ has $n$ elements, we can partition it into $k$ chosen fixed points and $n-k$ non-fixed points under $f$, and then $k^{n-k}$ is the number of different idempotent functions. Hence, taking into account all possible partitions,
$\sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} k^{n-k}$
is the total number of possible idempotent functions on the set. I mean you partition set and choose representative element for each part in all possible ways for each stage. https://oeis.org/A000248

Comment: So this is the number of idempotents of the semigroup $T_n$ of all transformations on $[n]$.